# Ruby on Rails: How to verify haml files syntax within rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment, haml

I've installed HAML into my project and it is working like a charm - the templates are beeing rendered without a problem. My question is how can I do the rendering on the command line, by using HAML program. That would be super for debugging purposes, meantime while I try to compile HAML file I get the error on first Rails related Ruby code to be found:

```
% cat app/views/dashboard/index.html.haml
- title "Home"
%p
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

% haml app/views/dashboard/index.html.haml
Exception on line 1: undefined method `title' for #<Object:0xb73283b0>
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Page is rendered fine returned correctly through the webserver.

Comment: @acidburn2k: I edited my answer, let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that you want to take a look at the [haml engine](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html)

```
template = File.read('templates/really_cool_template.haml')
haml_engine = Haml::Engine.new(template)
output = haml_engine.render
puts output
```

edit: Then put that into a rake task to load the rails environment. Once it's done you can pass all the parameters you want to your template

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `--check` flag on the Haml executable to check for syntax without evaluating the Ruby code:

```
% haml --check app/views/dashboard/index.html.haml
```

For future reference, the `--help` flag will print out all options for the executable.

Comment: This functionality is quite useless for me. If theres a syntax error, then Rails will display it in the browser during developement. What I need is to check the logic of the template and see whats the output.

Comment: I'm sorry... normally when one refers to the syntax of a template, one means the surface syntax, not the underlying semantics of the code.

In order to run the full template, you need to load the entire Rails stack and will likely need to have an actual HTTP request instantiated. This is not something that's well-suited for the command line.

Comment: hey @nex, great answer, thanks.  i was wondering whether there's a way to fix errors automatically ala `autopep8 --in-place` ?

Comment: This really helped me. Trying to fix legacy code and I was getting a rails error for a 500L haml with no indication where the error was. This check told me the line number.